# How to set a struct member that is a pointer to a string using reflection in Go

Tags: string, pointers, reflection, go, struct

I am trying to use reflection to set a pointer. `elasticbeanstalk.CreateEnvironmentInput` has a field `SolutionStackName` which is of type `*string`. I am getting the following error when I try to set any value:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetPointer on ptr Value
```

Here is my code:

```
    ...
newEnvCnf := new(elasticbeanstalk.CreateEnvironmentInput)
checkConfig2(newEnvCnf, "SolutionStackName", "teststring")
    ...
func checkConfig2(cnf interface{}, key string, value string) bool {
    log.Infof("key %v, value %s", key, value)

    v := reflect.ValueOf(cnf).Elem()
    fld := v.FieldByName(key)

    if fld.IsValid() {
        if fld.IsNil() && fld.CanSet() {
            fld.SetPointer(unsafe.Pointer(aws.String(value)))
//aws.String returns a pointer

...
```

Here is the log output

```
time="2016-02-20T23:54:52-08:00" level=info msg="key [SolutionStackName], value teststring" 
    panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetPointer on ptr Value [recovered]
        panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetPointer on ptr Value
```

Answer (score 8):

[`Value.SetPointer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.SetPointer) can only be used if the value's kind is `reflect.UnsafePointer` (as reported by [`Value.Kind()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Kind)), but yours is `reflect.Ptr` so `SetPointer()` will panic (as documented).

Simply use the [`Value.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) method to change the value of the struct field (it being pointer or not, doesn't matter). It expects an argument of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) which you can obtain by calling [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf), and simply pass the address of the parameter `value`:

```
fld.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&value))
```

Testing it:

```
type Config struct {
    SolutionStackName *string
}

c := new(Config)
fmt.Println(c.SolutionStackName)
checkConfig2(c, "SolutionStackName", "teststring")
fmt.Println(*c.SolutionStackName)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/OPDI13RBQ4)):

```
<nil>
teststring
```